# I am unable to transmit a CAN FD on STM32 Nucleo boards

Tags: c, embedded, can-bus, stm32cubeide, nucleo

I am attempting to transmit data over the Tx Pin of the Nucleo-G431RB. I have not been able to measure any signals coming over this pin with an oscilloscope. I know the problem is not the oscilloscope, as I am able to measure messages that come from a Value CAN.

**Here is my main. What I expect to happen is a signal to be sent over the Tx pin of my Nucleo. I want to be able to see this message on the oscilloscope as a first step in a larger test. The only thing I see on this pin is the ~3.3V level, with no square wave on it. I am able to go into debug mode and view the message being written into Tx Data**

```
* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2023 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "stdio.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
FDCAN_HandleTypeDef hfdcan1;

UART_HandleTypeDef hlpuart1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_LPUART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_FDCAN1_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

//Define variables to store the header and its data
FDCAN_TxHeaderTypeDef TxHeader;
FDCAN_RxHeaderTypeDef RxHeader;


uint8_t TxData[12];
uint8_t RxData[12];

int indx = 0;

void HAL_FDCAN_RxFifo0Callback(FDCAN_HandleTypeDef *hfdcan1, uint32_t RxFifo0ITs){
    if ((RxFifo0ITs & FDCAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_NEW_MESSAGE) != RESET){
        //Retreive Rx messages from RX FIFO0
        if (HAL_FDCAN_GetRxMessage(hfdcan1, FDCAN_RX_FIFO0, &RxHeader, RxData) !=HAL_OK){
            Error_Handler();
        }

        if (HAL_FDCAN_ActivateNotification(hfdcan1, FDCAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_NEW_MESSAGE, 0) != HAL_OK){
            Error_Handler();
        }
    }
}



/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_LPUART1_UART_Init();
  MX_FDCAN1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  if (HAL_FDCAN_Start(&hfdcan1) != HAL_OK) {
         Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_FDCAN_ActivateNotification(&hfdcan1, FDCAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_NEW_MESSAGE, 0 ) != HAL_OK){
      Error_Handler();
  }

  TxHeader.BitRateSwitch = FDCAN_BRS_OFF;
  TxHeader.DataLength = FDCAN_DLC_BYTES_12;
  TxHeader.ErrorStateIndicator = FDCAN_ESI_ACTIVE;
  TxHeader.FDFormat = FDCAN_FD_CAN;
  TxHeader.IdType = FDCAN_STANDARD_ID;
  TxHeader.Identifier = 0x11;
  TxHeader.MessageMarker = 0;
  TxHeader.TxEventFifoControl = FDCAN_NO_TX_EVENTS;
  TxHeader.TxFrameType = FDCAN_DATA_FRAME;




  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

      sprintf((char *)TxData, "FDCAN1TX %d", indx++);


      /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
     if (HAL_FDCAN_AddMessageToTxFifoQ(&hfdcan1, &TxHeader, TxData) != HAL_OK){
        Error_Handler();
     }

        HAL_Delay (1000);

        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = RCC_PLLM_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 18;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief FDCAN1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_FDCAN1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN FDCAN1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END FDCAN1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN FDCAN1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END FDCAN1_Init 1 */
  hfdcan1.Instance = FDCAN1;
  hfdcan1.Init.ClockDivider = FDCAN_CLOCK_DIV1;
  hfdcan1.Init.FrameFormat = FDCAN_FRAME_FD_NO_BRS;
  hfdcan1.Init.Mode = FDCAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hfdcan1.Init.AutoRetransmission = ENABLE;
  hfdcan1.Init.TransmitPause = DISABLE;
  hfdcan1.Init.ProtocolException = DISABLE;
  hfdcan1.Init.NominalPrescaler = 1;
  hfdcan1.Init.NominalSyncJumpWidth = 56;
  hfdcan1.Init.NominalTimeSeg1 = 231;
  hfdcan1.Init.NominalTimeSeg2 = 56;
  hfdcan1.Init.DataPrescaler = 8;
  hfdcan1.Init.DataSyncJumpWidth = 15;
  hfdcan1.Init.DataTimeSeg1 = 20;
  hfdcan1.Init.DataTimeSeg2 = 15;
  hfdcan1.Init.StdFiltersNbr = 1;
  hfdcan1.Init.ExtFiltersNbr = 0;
  hfdcan1.Init.TxFifoQueueMode = FDCAN_TX_FIFO_OPERATION;
  if (HAL_FDCAN_Init(&hfdcan1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN FDCAN1_Init 2 */
ee
  /* USER CODE END FDCAN1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief LPUART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_LPUART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN LPUART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END LPUART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN LPUART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END LPUART1_Init 1 */
  hlpuart1.Instance = LPUART1;
  hlpuart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  hlpuart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  hlpuart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  hlpuart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  hlpuart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  hlpuart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  hlpuart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  hlpuart1.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  hlpuart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&hlpuart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetTxFifoThreshold(&hlpuart1, UART_TXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetRxFifoThreshold(&hlpuart1, UART_RXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_DisableFifoMode(&hlpuart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN LPUART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END LPUART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : B1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LD2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LD2_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Comment: Troubleshooting checklist: ( 0) The most obvious - did you enable the CAN peripheral and did you send a message?) 1) Are there any other peripherals or GPIO mapped to this pin? If so, are there routing registers you must setup? Almost always the case these days. 2) Is the CAN peripheral getting the correct clock (or any clock at all)? 3) Is the CAN transceiver pin-out correct? 4) Are there any known STM32 HAL bugs that may apply? 5) Check the silicon errata for this part. Make this a habit for any MCU you use.

Comment: @Lundin 0 - I did enable FDCAN peripheral. I sent a message ...sprintf((char *)TxData, "FDCAN1TX %d", indx++);


      /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
     if (HAL_FDCAN_AddMessageToTxFifoQ(&hfdcan1, &TxHeader, TxData) != HAL_OK){
        Error_Handler();
     }

        HAL_Delay (1000);

Comment: @Lundin 1 - There are other peripheral that COULD be mapped to this peripheral, I am not sure how you mean. In STM32 Cube I have declared these pins as FDCAN. I am a bit confused about this question.

Comment: @Lundin 2 - The CAN signal is getting the correct clock, and the bit timing was exhaustively set up.

Comment: @Lunidn 3 - The CAN Transceiver pin out is correct.

Comment: @Lundin 4 - I have yet to find a list of HAL errors that includes CAN, but there seems to not be a singular list.

Comment: @Lundin 5 - In the Errata for FDCAN the one that seems closer to applying is to not use both a Tx Buffer and a Tx FIFO at the same time, or it may cause Tx FIFO message to invert? "Two consecutive messages from the Tx FIFO may be inverted in the transmit sequence if:
• FDCAN uses both a dedicated Tx buffer and a Tx FIFO (the TFQM bit of the FDCAN_TXBC register is
cleared), and
• the messages contained in the Tx buffer have a higher internal CAN priority than the messages in the Tx
FIFO."